A reasonable conversion in the member function pointer but an error occurred?
I always thought that when I converted a member function ptr in C to a member function ptr in A, I just had to make sure that the call was pointing to an C entity , but that was a mistake. Does the standard describe this use case in more detail?(checked with multiple compilers,MSVC GCC error,clang pass,This could be a compiler bug or undefined behavior?)
struct A
{
    char i[7];
    void test1(){
        std::cout << __LINE__;
    }
};

struct B
{
    char i[14];
    virtual void test(){
        std::cout << __LINE__;
    }
};

struct C:A,B
{
    char i[31];
};

using T = void (C::*)();

int main()
{
    C c;
    (c.*T(&B::test))();//good
    (c.*static_cast<decltype(&A::test1)>(T(&B::test)))();//crash
    return 0;
} 


The standard does not describe ill-formed programs. warning C4407: cast between different pointer to member representations, compiler may generate incorrect code.

@3CxEZiVlQ
In other words, even if I can guarantee that a base class pointer points to a derived class instance, is the upward conversion of member function pointers still dangerous?

&A::test1 is not an "address". You code smells like the ill-formed code char c = 'a'; int* p = static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(&c)); *p = 0;.

@3CxEZiVlQ I am just using it for type deduction. I previously wrote some other test cases, but in this test case, I don't want function overriding to occur, so I added a suffix.

&B::test is a pointer-to-member-of-B. You can convert it, with a cast, into a pointer-to-member-of-A, even though B::test is not a member of A, but you cannot use the result of that cast without converting it back to its original type.

@PeteBecker But according to cppref “Conversion in the opposite direction, from a pointer to member function of a derived class to a pointer to member function of an unambiguous non-virtual base class, is allowed with static_cast and explicit cast, even if the base class does not have that member function (but the most-derived class does, when the pointer is used for access)”I don't need to convert it back

In this area, the behavior of MSVC is non-standard by default - the size of pointer-to-member of class X depends on the properties of X (single inheritance vs multiple inheritance vs virtual inheritance), whereas the standard effectively requires them all to be the same size.  Compile with /vmg to select the standard behavior, or use inheritance keywors to control the representation on a class-by-class basis.

I printed out the sizes of various pointers-to-member. Here's the demo with /vmb (the default) - note different sizes, and the crash. Here's the demo with /vmg - all pointers are 24 bytes large. Here's the demo with /vmg /vmm - all pointers are 16 bytes large, but you would get a compiler error if you attempt to form a pointer-to-member of a class that uses virtual inheritance.

@余国良   You need to convert it back, in order to use it (e.g. use the pointer-to-member function to call the member function) without undefined behaviour.

@Peter The program is in fact well-defined.  It only fails to work due to a MSVC quirk.

@PeteBecker The program is valid as written. It is in fact allowed to cast a pointer-to-member of derived class to a pointer-to-member of base, and then call through that latter pointer, even if the base class does not contain the member. As long as the dynamic type of the object through which the call is made does contain the member. See expr.static.cast/12, and in particular the note at the end.

@3CxEZiVlQ  I ran some more tests, MSVC GCC error,clang pass

@IgorTandetnik -- A has no virtual functions; the dynamic type is just A. But that aside, I suspect that the rules have changed since I stopped paying careful attention.

@PeteBecker The object on which the pointer-to-member is invoked is c, and its dynamic type is C.
